# Letter counter gives wrong results

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I am making a program in C++ to count the number of letters in a text document.  I need to know what I am doing wrong, I am getting crazy numbers for results.  I had some good help last time and I put my "frequency[?]" after the counting.  Something is wrong with the counting itself, but what?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int ALPHA_SIZE = 26;

void open_file ( ifstream & );

void process ( ifstream &, int [], string lineBuffer);

void draw ( int [] );

void printchar ( int[] );

string lineBuffer;


int main()
{
    string lineBuffer;
    ifstream infile;
    open_file ( infile );

    int frequency [ALPHA_SIZE];

    process ( infile, frequency, lineBuffer);
        draw ( frequency );


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void open_file ( ifstream & inf )
{
    char infilename[50]; //actual file name
    cout << "File name for input? ";
    cin >> infilename;
    inf.open(infilename);
}

void process (ifstream &infile, int frequency[], string lineBuffer)
{

    int A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z;
    A = 0;
    B = 0;
    C = 0;
    D = 0;
    E = 0;
    F = 0;
    G = 0;
    H = 0;
    I = 0;
    J = 0;
    K = 0;
    L = 0;
    M = 0;
    N = 0;
    O = 0;
    P = 0;
    Q = 0;
    R = 0;
    S = 0;
    T = 0;
    U = 0;
    V = 0;
    W = 0;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    Z = 0;
    if (infile.is_open())
    {

        while(getline(infile, lineBuffer))

        {

        if ( 'a' ||  'A')
            { A++;
            }
        if ( 'b' ||  'B')
            {  B++;
            }
        if ( 'c' ||  'C')
            {  C++;
            }
        if ( 'd' ||  'D')
            {  D++;
            }
        if ( 'e' ||  'E')
            {  B++;
            }
        if ( 'f' ||  'F')
            {  F++;
            }
        if ( 'g' ||  'G')
            {  G++;
            }
        if ( 'h' ||  'H')
            {  H++;
            }
        if ( 'i' ||  'I')
            {  I++;
            }
        if ( 'j' ||  'J')
            {  J++;
            }
        if ( 'k' ||  'K')
            {  K++;
            }
        if ( 'l' ||  'L')
            {  L++;
            }
        if ( 'm' ||  'M')
            {  M++;
            }
        if ( 'n' ||  'N')
            {  N++;
            }
        if ( 'o' ||  'O')
            {  O++;
            }
        if ( 'p' ||  'P')
            {  P++;
            }
        if ( 'q' ||  'Q')
            {  Q++;
            }
        if ( 'r' ||  'R')
            {  R++;
            }
        if ( 's' ||  'S')
            {  S++;
            }
        if ( 't' ||  'T')
            {  T++;
            }
        if ( 'u' ||  'U')
            {  U++;
            }
        if ( 'v' ||  'V')
            {  V++;
            }
        if ( 'w' ||  'W')
            {  W++;
            }
        if ( 'x' ||  'X')
            {  X++;
            }
        if ( 'y' ||  'Y')
            {  Y++;
            }
        if ( 'z' ||  'Z')
            {  Z++;
            }
          }
        infile.close();
        frequency [0] = A;
        frequency [1] = B;
        frequency [2] = C;
        frequency [3] = D;
        frequency [4] = E;
        frequency [5] = F;
        frequency [6] = G;
        frequency [7] = H;
        frequency [8] = I;
        frequency [9] = J;
        frequency [10] = K;
        frequency [11] = L;
        frequency [12] = M;
        frequency [13] = N;
        frequency [14] = O;
        frequency [15] = P;
        frequency [16] = Q;
        frequency [17] = R;
        frequency [18] = S;
        frequency [19] = T;
        frequency [20] = U;
        frequency [21] = V;
        frequency [22] = W;
        frequency [23] = X;
        frequency [24] = Y;
        frequency [25] = Z;


    }
}

void draw(int frequency[])
{
    cout << "A:" << frequency[0] << endl;
    cout << "B:" << frequency[1] << endl;
    cout << "C:" << frequency[2] << endl;
    cout << "D:" << frequency[3]<< endl;
    cout << "E:" << frequency[4] << endl;
    cout << "F:" << frequency[5] << endl;
    cout << "G:" << frequency[6] << endl;
    cout << "H:" << frequency[7] << endl;
    cout << "I:" << frequency[8] << endl;
    cout << "J:" << frequency[9] << endl;
    cout << "K:" << frequency[10] << endl;
    cout << "L:" << frequency[11] << endl;
    cout << "M:" << frequency[12] << endl;
    cout << "N:" << frequency[13] << endl;
    cout << "O:" << frequency[14] << endl;
    cout << "P:" << frequency[15] << endl;
    cout << "Q:" << frequency[16] << endl;
    cout << "R:" << frequency[17] << endl;
    cout << "S:" << frequency[18] << endl;
    cout << "T:" << frequency[19] << endl;
    cout << "U:" << frequency[20] << endl;
    cout << "V:" << frequency[21] << endl;
    cout << "W:" << frequency[22] << endl;
    cout << "X:" << frequency[23] << endl;
    cout << "Y:" << frequency[24] << endl;
    cout << "Z:" << frequency[25] << endl;

}
```

Comment: Arrays and loops will save you from all that typing.

Comment: 'a' ||  'A' -> true, 'b' || 'B' -> true... this is going to be aparty

Comment: What is the question? And where? Telling us that you "ran into another mistake" does not a question make.

Comment: What did you do?  [Your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326029/) didn't have these problems...

Comment: @JesseGood, Technically you can't always take a loop shortcut through letters, as ASCII isn't guaranteed, but `<cctype>` helps.

Comment: `if ( 'e' ||  'E') {  B++; }` Hrmm...

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah I saw that when I looked over it. Thanks for noticing.
I guess I really just don't understand much about this new material DarkGDK was pampering me I guess and they took that out of the curriculum so now I need to relearn or learn the real way to do it.

Comment: @Mooing Duck You pointed out that I had to stick the frequency[?] after the count.

Comment: @MysterymanMysteryman: yes I did, but then you replaced perfectly working code with `while(getline(infile, lineBuffer))` in that same function, which makes everything not work.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh, I did change that though it might work.  I made a few copies of the file and tried different things on multiple copies.  I have 2 tabs open.

Comment: @Mooing Duck I changed that back and took mathematician1975 advice and made a test variable.  Trying to put up the changed copy.

Answer (score 3):

Each of these conditionals

```
 if ( 'n' ||  'N')
```

will always evaluate to true since they are non-zero constant char values. Therefore, your variables you are using to count are always incremented. To test for the incidence of a character, you need something like this

```
char char_to_test;
if (char_to_test == 'n' || char_to_test == 'N') {
    N++;
}
```

what you currently have always increments your count. Furthermore, you need to actually extract each character from the file in order to do the testing. Once you get the `string` from `getline`, you should iterate over its individual characters and test them as above.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, this is only my second semester, and I have to relearn a lot since they aren't teaching DarkGDK anymore.

Comment: You need to extract each character from the string and TEST if it is equal to the character you want. Your tests are just doing this `if ('n' != 0 || 'N' != 0)` at the moment. Clearly they are never `0` and so each statement inside your if blocks are executed REGARDLESS

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of problems.

One of them is the fact that you're calling a function to open the file.

`void open_file ( ifstream & inf )`

This function would close the file once the scope on it is gone.

All your variables have a lot of repetitive code that could easily be made more compact if loops were used.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<char,int> alpha;
    //Fills the map with A-Z with 0 as the value.
    for(char k = 65; k <= 90; k++) {
        alpha.insert(std::pair<char,int>(k,0));
    }
    //opens example.txt contains "the quick brown fox jumped over the cow"
    std::ifstream in("example.txt");
    std::string str;
    if(in.is_open()) {
        //loops through every line in the file.
        while(std::getline(in,str)) {
            //removes all whitespace
            str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(), ::isspace),str.end());
            //capitalizes the string
            std::transform(str.begin(),str.end(),str.begin(), ::toupper);
            //loops through the string
            for(auto& i : str) {
                if(isalpha(i))
                    alpha[i]++; //Increments the frequency.
            }
        }
    }
    for(auto& i : alpha)
        std::cout << i.first << " " << i.second << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the program to make sure it only reads each character once. This is similar to this problem: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/24492/
You have to tell the program when to end. What you asking the program to do is "While A exists in the file A++" Well it always exists in the file. You could this: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/

This will help it zip through the file, char by char. You still have to figure out how to make it stop at the end of the file.

Comment: That makes sense now, so with the character test using char whatever it will test each one.  So the crazy numbers are due to my programming agreeing with everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to work on being lazier. Here's a version in C:

```
unsigned counts[UCHAR_MAX];

int main() {  
    int ch;

    while (EOF != (ch=getchar()))
        ++counts[toupper((unsigned char)ch)];

    for (int i=0; i<UCHAR_MAX; i++)
        if (isupper(i))
            printf("%c: %u\n", i, counts[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I've simplified a little bit (e.g., reading of `stdin` instead of opening a file), but this is ultimately a pretty simple job -- don't try to make a a lot more complex than it really is.